# ASP.Net white page of death after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have two ASP.NET (4.0) web applications running on IIS 8.5. Periodically, the users will try to log in and after submitting their credentials, the page will reload into a white screen.

The response size is 0 bytes and has a 200 status. The login page will reload and the HTML will be displayed, but when you submit the form the white page will be displayed. This is solved when the application pool is recycled.

I have checked the IIS logs and event viewer and there are no errors or warning related to this issue.

The code for the login.aspx page is below:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/login.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Driver.login1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .has-error {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span id="spnInvalidAccount" runat="server" visible="false" class="has-error">Invalid Credentials</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <asp:TextBox TextMode="SingleLine" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Box Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" CssClass="has-error" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Careem Id Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" CssClass="has-error" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Password Required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <span class="checkbox">
                <div class="icheckbox_flat-red col-xs-1" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;">
                    <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxRememberMe" runat="server" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;" />--%>
                    <input id="Login1_RememberMe" runat="server" type="checkbox" name="Login1$RememberMe" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
                </div>
                <label for="Login1_RememberMe" class="col-xs-9">Remember me</label>

            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Sign In" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Driver
{
    public partial class login1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["action"] != null && Request.QueryString["action"] == "logout")
                {
                    HttpCookie loggedInCookie = new HttpCookie("LoggedIn");
                    loggedInCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(loggedInCookie);
                }
                else if (Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"] != null && Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"].Value != null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
                }
            }
            if (Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"] != null && Request.Cookies["LoggedIn"].Value != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DriverEntities cnx = new DriverEntities())
            {
                string password = Global.EncryptPassword(txtPassword.Text);
                if (cnx.Drivers.Where(x => x.BoxNumber == txtEmail.Text && x.Password == password).Any())
                {
                    Driver driver = cnx.Drivers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BoxNumber == txtEmail.Text && x.Password == password);
                    Car car = cnx.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == driver.CarId);
                    HttpCookie loggedInCookie = new HttpCookie("LoggedIn");
                    loggedInCookie.Value = driver.Id.ToString();
                    if (!Login1_RememberMe.Checked)
                        loggedInCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
                    else
                        loggedInCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(loggedInCookie);
                    HttpCookie carCookie = new HttpCookie("MV_car");
                    carCookie.Value = car.Id.ToString();
                    Response.Cookies.Add(carCookie);
                    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    spnInvalidAccount.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some Remarks:**
- I haven't been able to recreate this issue locally. This is only happening in the production environment.
- We use the same login page for a dozen other applications and we haven't had the same issue with them.
- The page is not redirecting to the default.aspx page.
- Customerrors is turned off so if there was an application error we would be able to see the exception screen

Comment: Maybe adding some logging to the page reveals the culprit?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried adding logs in the code to try and debug the issue. The application is executing the entire function without any apparent error.